# What exactly does it mean for a maximal ideal to be unique in a principal ideal domain?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

I'm currently reading about PIDs and have come across a question involving maximal ideals which at one point reads "Suppose that a Euclidean domain $R$ had a unique maxima ideal $P$". Does this mean that $P$ is the only maximal ideal? Or that if $P = \langle p \rangle$ it cannot also equal $\langle p_1 \rangle$ for another prime $p_1$?

Comment: It means $P$ is the only maximal ideal.

Comment: Thank you, that makes the question much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each nonzero ring with identity (even the noncommutative ones) has at least one maximal ideal. To say it has a unique maximal ideal means that it has exactly one and no more.

Commutative rings which have a unique maximal ideal are called [local rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring), and they are a key thing in commutative algebra.